# Solution to a recurrence relation (A variation of Josephus' Problem)

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

The recurrence relation in question:
$$
S\left(n+1\right)\ =\ S\left(n\right)\ if\ S\left(n\right)\ \ge2n
$$
$$
S\left(n+1\right)\ =\ S\left(n\right)+n+1\ if\ S\left(n\right)\ <2n
$$
$$
S(1)= 0
$$

I was revisiting the chapter "Recurrent Problems" in "Concrete Mathematics" by Donald Knuth, Ronald Graham and Oren Patashnick. The last introductory problem in the chapter was Josephus' Problem (the modification of the original problem that killed every other person, instead of every third person, which was how it was in Josephus' tale). In essence, you have n people in a circle and every second person is killed. The objective is to find the position of the survivor within the circle for any natural number 'n'. Having solved the case of every second person being killed, I set about to solve the case where every third person is executed. After attempting to find patterns, I found these recurrence relations [J(n) is the survivor when n people are in a circle]:

$$
J\left(3n\right)\ =\ J\left(2n\right)\ +\ \operatorname{floor}\left(\frac{J\left(2n\right)-1}{2}\right)
$$

I haven't found the above one particularly helpful so far. The following one, I did.

$$
J\left(n+1\right)\ =\ J\left(n\right)\ +\ 3\ if\ J\left(n\right)\ \le n\ -\ 2
$$

$$
J\left(n+1\right)\ =\ J\left(n\right)\ +\ 2\ -\ n\ if\ J\left(n\right)\ >\ n\ -\ 2
$$
$$
J(1) = 1
$$
After some deliberation, I hypothesized that:
$$
J\left(n\right)\ =\ 3n\ -\ 2-S\left(n\right)
$$
Where S(n) is solution the "recurrence relation" in question. So far, none of my attempts to find the solution have been fruitful. The recurrent relation for S(n) was found by plugging my "hypothesis equation" into the recurrent relation relating J(n+1) to J(n). Could I get some help with solving the relation, or some other method that would be a better fit for this problem?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep that in mind, going forward.

Comment: Maybe start "going forward" now, and edit the post?